# CORS error when creating checkout session in Stripe

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am developing using stripe.
I created a checkout session, but got the error below.
How can I resolve this?

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/createCheckoutSession' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

src/Purchase.ts

```
import React from "react";
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { functions } from "../firebase";

function Purchase() {
  // ...
  const createCheckoutSession = httpsCallable(functions, "createCheckoutSession");
  createCheckoutSession({
    priceId: "price id",
  });
}

export default Purchase;
```

functions/indes.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
```

import Stripe from "stripe";

```
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.secret, {
    apiVersion: "2022-11-15",
});

export const createCheckoutSession = () => functions
    .region("asia-northeast1")
    .https.onCall(async (data) => {
      const priceId = data.priceId;

      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [{
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
        }],
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: "",
        cancel_url: "",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
      });
      return session;
    });
```

src/firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID  ,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app, "asia-northeast1");

export default app;
```

Comment: What do you see when you visit the cloud function's URL from a browser?

Comment: I got "Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /createCheckoutSession from this server."

Comment: Two functions are written in "index.ts".
Could that be the reason?

Comment: Multiple functions can exist in the same `index.ts` file, so that won't be it. Have you checked whether your function can be [invoked by the `allUsers` group](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment)?

Comment: sorry. I solved it by changing "export const createCheckoutSession = () => functions" to "export const createCheckoutSession = functions". Function was not deployed.

Comment: Good spot. Kind of annoyed I didn't see it now that it has been pointed out.

Comment: @Ika, Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function was not deployed.

before

```
export const createCheckoutSession = () => functions
```

after

```
export const createCheckoutSession = functions
```